# Heat, work, energy and ideal gas law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, work, ideal-gas

I have encountered a textbook problem which I believe I have solved correctly, but my text book gives a slightly different answer. Any input will be greatly appreciated!

**PROBLEM:**

A container has a volume of $10$ dm$^3$ and contains $130$ g of an ideal gas. The temperature is $293$ K and the pressure outside of the container is $1\cdot10^6$ Pa.

The temperature then increases to $410.2$ K, and the volume increases to $14$ dm$^3$. The pressure remains constant.

a) How much work is done by the gas on the surroundings?

b) How much heat do we have to add to the gas?

**MY SOLUTION:**

a) The work done by the gas on the surroundings is equal to $W=p\Delta V$. Thus, we get:

$W=10^6 \cdot (0.014-0.01) = 4000$ J.

This is correct according to the book as well. So far, so good!

b) From a) I know the work done by the gas on the surroundings. Using the first law of thermodynamics, I can solve for the heat, $Q$ via the equation:

$\Delta U= Q + W$.

To find $\Delta U$, I estimated the kinetic energy of the gas at the two different temperatures. $\Delta U$ should then be equal to the difference in kinetic energy.

First I find the number of molecules in the gas via the equation:

$PV=NkT$

This yields

$N=\frac{PV}{kT}$

Using the initial values for $P$, $V$ and $T$ and the Boltzmann constant, $k$, gives me:

$N=\frac{10^6 \cdot 0.01}{1.38\cdot10^{-23} \cdot293}$

$N\approx2.473\cdot10^{24}$

I get the same answer for $N$ also when I use the new values for these parameters. So the number of molecules in the gas is constant.

The initial kinetic energy is thus equal to:

$Ek_1 = N\cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot k \cdot T_1 = 2.473\cdot10^{24} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot 1,38\cdot10^{-23} \cdot 293 = 15000$ J.

The new kinetic energy is:

$Ek_2 = N\cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot k \cdot T_2 = 2.473\cdot10^{24} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot 1,38\cdot10^{-23} \cdot 410.2 = 21000$ J.

So $\Delta U = 21000 - 15000 = 6000$ J.

This gives:

$6000 = Q - 4000$

$Q = 6000 + 4000 = 10000$ J $= 10$ kJ.

However, according to my book, the final answer should be $12$ kJ.

I really can't see what I have done wrong, so if anyone can help me out a little bit here, then I would truly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm your result of 10 kJ, assuming a mono-atomic gas.  The molecular weight of this gas is about 32, suggesting a diatomic gas, maybe oxygen.  For a diatomic gas, the molar heat capacity at constant volume is 2.5R.  This would result in a heat load of 14 kJ, rather than 10 kJ.  Neither of these results match the book value of 12 kJ.

Comment: You probably mean oxygen not nitrogen.

Comment: Thank you very much for verifying my result!

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Thanks Jeffrey.  Senior moment.